# new to IOS, does it really matter if we start writing code in viewcontroller class.. or do we have to create a new class

Tags: ios

I am trying to figure out if there is really any problem dumping all my code in viewcontroller calls. Is there really any difference if you put code in viewcontroller vs. a new class?

Comment: by a "new class" do you mean a new UIViewController subclass? Or do you mean some other class for some other function?

Answer (score 2):

As @BergQuester notes, Cocoa relies heavily on MVC. Data goes into its own classes, called "Models", which should not rely on any specific display logic; these are often simple data classes, but may also include network connection logic, database management, etc. The point is that model classes should not care how they are displayed.

The "View" classes display things; these are mostly provided by Apple.

The Controllers live between the views and the model, shuffling events and data between them. The View Controllers specifically are there to manage what a view displays and user interaction.

You should not put all of your logic in the view controllers. In particular, view controllers should not do anything related to the network, and should not do anything that assumes that they will be around for a long time (since view controller often come and go with their views). All of the data management should be handled at the model layer.

Answer (score 1):

Cocoa heavily uses the [Model-View-Controller (MVC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html) model to determine where code goes. One *could* do it some other way, but you'll end up fighting the framework.

Comment: so are you saying do not use viewcontroller class ?

Comment: You should not use the view controller class to do things that are not controlling a view (i.e. managing how the view displays data and responding to user input).